# Convert period/duration time format from MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a MySQL database that stores time periods/durations in the format 'PTxxMxxS'.

I want to convert to standard time format, so for example I want to convert PT4M17S to 04:17.

I have tried various combinations of STR_TO_DATE and TIME_FORMAT without any success.

I've searched but I can't find a solution - I think part of the problem is that I don't know what this type of time formatting is called.

Thanks.

Comment: mysql date/time fields are for actual dates/times. you're storing intervals/durations, which won't map cleanly to a date/time. e.g. `PT999H` is a valid interval, but if you stuff that into a mysql time field, it'll get corrupted, because mysql times are +/- 838 hours, roughly. arbitrary intervals should probably be converted to something else, like a raw integer representing seconds. those can easily be converted back to an interval-formatting with some code, but you can't convert/use a corrupted time value.

Comment: For valid time periods you could use the str_to_date() function to convert the above format to MySQL's time format. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: This is a database that I'm having to get data from so I have no control over its content - the time format PTxxMxxS is just something I have to deal with. I've tried using STR_TO_DATE(fieldvalue, '%h:%i:%s) and similar with TIME_FORMAT

Comment: @jhTuppeny - the second argument of STR_TO_DATE should represent the format you have as input. ` '%h:%i:%s` is not the format of `PTxxMxxS`. Try and find how `PTxxMxxS` should be represented in MySQL time format, which will make STR_TO_DATE work. Still, see top comment above to make sure you actually want to translate this to a datetime field..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mysql documentation on [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function says:

> The server scans str attempting to match format to it.

The above means that the format parameter is used to parse the input string, not to format the output of the result. This is why your conversion failed.

The below call will convert a time from 'PTxxMxxS' format to standard mysql time format (no need to specify the last S character in the format parameter, but you can add it if you want that, does not matter).

```
STR_TO_DATE(fieldvalue, 'PT%iM%s')
```

However, as @MarcB has already pointed out, mysql's [time data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) has restrictions on its range and therefore a simple conversion using the str_to_date() function may not be adequate for you. Check your data before applying the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all the comments - much appreciated. A combination of STR_TO_DATE and TIME_FORMAT worked.